# How to prevent caption removal after tabulator is applied

Tags: tabulator

The table captions are missing after tabulator is applied. Alternatively, how can I set caption after tabulator has been applied?

Comment: My post was tagged for [tabulator]. Are you aware of tabulator?

Comment: Just trying to help , but since you ask see my profile you can see tabulator tag SCORE
11
POSTS
51

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved on the github site. 
https://github.com/olifolkerd/tabulator/issues/2279

I had posted the question on Stackoverflow because of the recommendations from the github site:
https://github.com/olifolkerd/tabulator/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=question.md&title=

[image]